# Pricing differences between AWS SimpleDB and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-simpledb

I'm having trouble understanding the pricing differences between SimpleDB and DyanmoDD (and let's say, RDS).  From what I understand, with SimpleDB, you pay for the amount of raw data that you're storing every month, and then you pay for machine utilization time whenever your upload or query your data.  So, in a given month, if you never query or upload any data, you'll only pay for the data that's sitting there.  With DynamoDB and RDS, it seems like you're paying for server capacity-hours all the time, every month (especially RDS?).  Is that right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

SimpleDB has a fixed size limit because it indexes everything every way possible. You pay for the data you have, and for the query time, plus data out.

DynamnoDB, you pay for data you have ($0.25/gb/m) plus query capability (Q*$0.0065/h = Q*$4.68/m).  plus data out.

RDS you pay for a server (smallest is $0.017 = $12.24/m) plus storage ($0.115/gb/m for total capacity) plus  data out.

EC2 would be the same as RDS, but cheaper per server hour.  But you have to manage it yourself.

So RDS is "wasteful" in that you pay for the disk size, not for the data in the DB. You also pay the same for an idle database as for a busy one. (I'm ignoring data, since that's the same between all of them, and rarely a factor.)   On the other hand, a fix size allows you to budget: You won't suddenly pay more because your app goes wild. (Worst case, you restart your database on a bigger server.)